# Python 3 why this simple interest code prints the last calculated simple interest value when i check the try and except case?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

```
    def simple_interest(p,r,t):
        s =(p*r*t)/100
        print(s)
    try:
        p = float(input('enter 
        Principal amount:'))
        r = float(input('enter 
        rate:'))
        t = float(input('enter 
        time period:'))
    except:
        print('invalid 
              input')
    simple_interest(p,r,t)
```

Output : enter principal amount:
hello
Invalid input
1800.00

Answer (score 0):

```
def simple_interest(p,r,t):
    try:
        p = float(input('enter Principal amount:'))
        r = float(input('enter rate:'))
        t = float(input('enter time period:'))

        s =(p*r*t)/100
        print(s)
    except:
        print('invalid input')
    
simple_interest(p,r,t)
```